# New PS Plus subscription won't work

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I bought my son a PS Plus subscription yesterday and he is still not able to play any multiplayer games. When I go into Settings/Network (either mine as the family manager or his), it says "These users (his online ID) cannot use the application due to parental controls." But I've changed all the parental controls I can that would allow it. I've even temporarily disabled all restrictions and still nothing.

And for example, in NBA2K20, he's not able to enter MyCareer mode, because of parental controls.

Anyone ever have a similar issue?